# Unable to put a function within a list

Tags: python

I've been trying to create an enigma machine that uses as many rotors as the user want.
So, I've created this function : `def enigma(uncrypted_string,n_of_rotors):`

To perform this, I've used a loop that defines lambda functions, and then i put them inside a list :

```
  rotors=[]
  crypted_string=[]
  for i in range(n_of_rotors):
    i= lambda character,current_number: chr((ord(character) + current_number - 97) % 26 + 97)
    rotors.append(i)
```

I then use a loop to encrypt multiple times each letter.

```
for char in uncrypted_string:
    current_letter = char
    position +=1
    for r in rotors:
      current_letter = rotors[r](current_letter,1)
    crypted_string.append(current_letter)
```

The problem is that i get this error, and I don't know how to reprogram my machine to do the same thing :

```
current_letter = rotors[r](current_letter,1)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not function
```

Obviously I searched the web for the error that I was getting, but I didn't find anything similar to my problem... Can someone help me, please ?

Comment: `r` is a function from `rotors`, not an index in the list, so just call `r` instead of `rotors[r]`. By the way, there doesn't seem to be any difference whatsoever between the functions in your list.

Comment: Agree with @kaya3. You just need to change this line 
`current_letter = rotors[r](current_letter,1)` 
to this 
`current_letter = r(current_letter,1)`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is you are trying to access the index positions of the list rotors using a function. As the error says, you can only access index using integers or slices.

in your `for r in rotors:` loop, r is already a function because it is going through the list rotors. So, you don't need to use `rotors[r]` to use the function r. 
To fix your code, replace

```
current_letter = rotors[r](current_letter,1)
```

To

```
current_letter = r(current_letter,1)
```